# Creating several output nodes, from the scope of a single input node in a Biztalk visual map

Tags: xml, xslt, maps, schema, biztalk

My problem is like so:

In my input file I have a record, that contains an element with a number. This record only occurs once.

In my output file, I need to create 2 records, that contain this number.

Using a looping functoid does not suit my purpose, since only a single record is created in the output file.

My input schema (Odette number is the element I need to map):

[image]

My output schema:

[image]

So I need to create 2 occurences of NADLoop1, each containing the OdetteNumber. 
I tried using a table looping functoid, but since NadLoop1 is already involved in several other loops in the map, I receive an error saying "The variable or parameter 'var' is either not defined or it is out of scope"

If possible I would like to avoid using XSLT, as the rest of the map is made using the visual mapper, but if that's the only solution, I am willing to implement it in XSLT.

Comment: In order to stay in topic, I think you should ask for the `biztalk` solution you want. In case there is no one, you could ask for a more general `XSLT` solution. Do note that for the last one you need to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

In the output EDI Schema, you can create a dedicated NAD (not NADLoop1) for each of the values, NAD_1 and NAD_2 for example.

Custom EDI fields are described here: [BizTalk Server: EDI Features Not Just For HIPAA](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27099.biztalk-server-edi-features-not-just-for-hipaa.aspx)

It's basically copying the definition for NAD and renaming the NAD element.

Please don't forget to mark Answers as helpful or Accepted if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not allowed to alter the schema definition. I can see how your solution would work though.

Comment: @Leth The thing is that makes it a lot harder. If you explain their objection we can help you explain why they're, well, wrong.